# Image Viewer like Windows Image Viewer

Tags: macos, mac, applications, graphics, image-editing

I want a good image viewer for mac. When I open any random image from a folder like this:

[image: her]

I want to be able to navigate to next/previous image with left and right arrow. Seems so simple but I downloaded 15 image viewers for mac and couldn't find the one I am looking for.

The default imageviewer for Windows does this perfectly. I want something like it: https://youtu.be/kWwjm-2U_mU?t=1m1s

Answer (score 6):

You could try just using Quick Look, built into the OS.

Select any of the images, tap the Space Bar.
Navigate the way you normally would inside the folder, up/down/left/right arrows.
Tap Space again to close.

This works for more than just pictures, it can handle music, text files, movies etc. & is extendable with new plugins. There's a list here [I don't know how comprehensive] - http://www.quicklookplugins.com

Comment: With quicklook you need to use down and up arrows as well to navigate

Comment: The screencapped pic looks like it is just one of the Icon views in Windows Explorer. So use Icon View in the Finder and then select a slightly larger icon size and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [best Windows-like photo viewer](https://www.widsmob.com/viewer) you can try. It is free to download.

You can open a folder and double-click any image to start browsing with left or right arrows.

Note:

1. You can click "+" icon on the top left corner of the screen to add new folders to browse.
2. You can click the "Play" icon at the bottom to view images in slideshow mode. 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I missed this on MacOS from the beginning. So I made my own :-)

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1226444549

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is an image viewer called [Picview](https://enpicsee.chitaner.com). Its interface and logic are very similar to the default photo viewer on Windows. You can download and use it for free.

Additionally, it is natively programmed using Swift, so the installer package is only 7.1MB. It responds quickly and is extremely efficient.

[image]